# Однородные сказуемые при одном дополнении

Tags: синтаксис, управление, сказуемые, однородные-члены, дополнение

**Охотно соглашайся и даже сам предлагай взять на себя выполнение новых функций, которые не относятся к твоим текущим обязанностям.**

**Найди и подпишись на сообщество компании в соцсетях.**

Можно ли по литературным нормам так составлять предложения, т.е. чтобы однородные сказуемые управляли одним дополнением? Прошу ещё заметить, что во втором примере глаголы требуют после себя дополнения разного вида (прямого и косвенного).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое предложение корректно (соглашайся взять и предлагай взять). А во втором, на мой взгляд, **неверное** управление (найди на сообщество(?!) и подпишись на сообщество), которое никакой контекст не извиняет.

> [§205. Управление при однородных членах предложения](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm)
>   При двух или нескольких управляющих словах общее зависимое слово допустимо, когда каждое из управляющих слов требует того же падежа и **предлога**, например: читать и конспектировать книгу; подбирать и готовить кадры; протравливать и яровизировать семена; надеяться и рассчитывать на помощь.
>   Наличие общего зависимого слова при различном управлении нарушает грамматико-стилистическую норму, например: «с помощью и в сотрудничестве с местными организациями» (ср. правильный вариант: с помощью местных организаций и в сотрудничестве с ними), «организация и руководство стачечной борьбой»; «в соответствии и на основе утвержденного плана»; «надеяться и верить в возможность»; «руководство и контроль за распределением гуманитарной помощи».
>
> Изредка подобные конструкции встречаются у писателей, например: жмурил и хлопал глазами (Гоголь); ловя и избегая вопросительно устремленный на него взор Кати (Тургенев); препятствует или затягивает достижение соглашения (Эренбург).

Answer (score 1):

Пример (1) соответствует норме, а пример (2) нужно смотреть в контексте, он выглядит как неполное предложение.

**Примеры управления:**

**Найди и отметь** ошибки в тексте.

Если ты **напишешь и даже напечатаешь** книгу, то известным писателем всё равно не станешь.

Кстати, частица *даже* дифференцирует однородные члены, так что они не чисто однородные, а с дополнительным значением у одного их них.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что если здесь неполное предложение с пропущенным прямым дополнением "сообщество" ("найди сообщество") при первом однородном члене, то ошибки не будет?

Comment: В неполном предложении смысл пропущенного слова должен быть ясен из предыдущего текста, тогда это нормально.

Comment: Мне кажется, здесь всё-таки явно бросается в глаза разное управление глаголов и якобы неполным предложением тут не отвертишься. Можете привести примеры таких случаев, с пропущенным дополнением? А пока возможная правка: "Найди сообщество компании в соцсетях и подпишись на него".

Comment: Я не могу привести таких примеров, а ваша правка вполне корректна. А по поводу контекста можно предположить такой вариант: найди (необходимую информацию, то есть узнай, как это делается) и подпишись на сообщество компании в соцсетях. Нужно видеть предыдущий текст.