# Ошибка с управлением у сказуемых в неполном предложении

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, управление, дополнение

*Надо бы ему зарплату поднять и в должности повысить.*

Здесь неполное предложение: для благозвучия пропущено местоимение "его" ("в должности его повысить"). И из-за пропуска кажется, что местоимение "ему" относится и к глаголу "повысить", которое имеет другое управление.

Comment: В чем вопрос, уточните. Ошибки, кстати, я не вижу.

Comment: @Мимоходов "Повысить ему в должности"

Comment: То есть вопрос именно в том, есть ли ошибка? Это не ошибка, а правила употребления разносогласуемых однородных членов.

Comment: Не могу сказать, является ли ошибкой, но если и приемлемо, то только в разговорной речи. (Выражение *надо бы* как раз показывает, что это разговорная речь.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо бы ему зарплату поднять и в должности (его) повысить.

Ошибки нет:  пропущенное во избежание повтора местоимение ***его*** восстанавливается **по тексту** в нужной падежной форме, а не повторяет форму предыдущего местоимения.

Comment: Ответьте, пожалуйста, на мой комментарий (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/438166/Однородные-сказуемые-при-одном-дополнении). Там похожая ситуация с однородными сказуемыми, имеющими разное управление. Там вы также допускаете неполное предложение.

Comment: Это разные конструкции.  (1)  Надо бы ЕМУ зарплату поднять и в должности (его) повысить.    Здесь  мы подбираем нужную форму местоимения ОН, названного в первой части.    (2) Найди и подпишись на сообщество компании в соцсетях.  Здесь глаголы, связанные союзом И, стоят перед предлогом НА, так что их можно отнести к одной падежной форме.

Comment: Значит, в предложении (2) ошибка есть?

Comment: Это не ошибка, а допустимый в некоторых случаях разговорный вариант. К тому же, как мне кажется,  всё предложение носит разговорный характер. Искать  надо страницу компании в соцсетях, если она там есть,  а выражение "подпишись на сообщество" тоже достаточно условно. Поэтому  оценка "есть ошибка /нет ошибки"  не всегда правильна. То, что в академическом стиле сочтут за ошибку, то в разговорном вполне допустимо и даже иногда более уместно.

Comment: Ещё вопрос: пропущенное местоимение восстанавливается в нужной падежной форме даже с предлогом? "Хвалит ли он других людей, или смеётся (над ними) и унижает?"

Comment: Думаю, что верен такой вариант: Хвалит ли он других людей или унижает (их) и смеётся над ними?