# Неполное предложение с пропущенным местоимением-дополнением

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, грамматика, управление, дополнение

Данный вопрос появился из [этого](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440792/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8). В нём разбиралось предложение:

1. *Надо бы ему зарплату поднять и в должности повысить.*

Здесь нет ошибки употребления одного дополнения при однородных членах с разным управлением. Пропущенное во избежание повтора местоимение "его" легко восстанавливается. Однако я заметил, что легко восстанавливается только пропущенное местоимение в винительном падеже, то есть которое является прямым дополнением. Так ли это? Например, пропущенная форма дательного падежа местоимения будет совсем не очевидна при прочтении:

2. *Надо бы его в должности повысить и зарплату поднять.*

Comment: Действительно, здесь форма д.п. неочевидна. Но можно ведь исправить. ... и повысить ему зарплату.

Comment: @Серж Тогда будет повтор местоимения, а это некрасиво.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Надо бы его в должности повысить и зарплату*** (его? ему?) ***поднять.***

Второе предложение действительно звучит **не совсем корректно.**  Я думаю, что дело здесь  не в  падежах, а в том, что слово ***его*** выполняет двойную функцию: оно может быть **личным или притяжательным** местоимением.

Если мы используем личное местоимение ***его*** в первой части предложения, то во второй части может подразумеваться повтор того же слова, но уже **в функции притяжательного местоимения**:

***Надо бы его в должности повысить и зарплату*** (его) ***поднять.***  Некорректность же заключается в том, что в действительности там  требуется личное местоимение ***ему*** (в форме Д.п.).

Сравнить: ***Надо бы ему зарплату поднять и в должности*** (его) ***повысить.***  Очевидно, что здесь однозначно подходит только местоимение ***его***, но не ***ему***.

Comment: «Если мы используем личное местоимение *его* в первой части предложения, то во второй части может подразумеваться повтор того же слова, но уже в функции притяжательного местоимения: *Надо бы его в должности повысить и зарплату (его) поднять*». Мне с трудом представляется, что можно предположить притяжательное местоимение «его» во второй части. Хоть и форма одна, личное местоимение и притяжательное — разные члены предложения: дополнение и определение. Если в первой части дополнение, то и во второй, должно быть, тоже. Читатель не будет выдумывать там определение лишь из-за одинаковой формы.

Comment: Выдумывать и подставлять он не будет, но неоднозначность конструкции ощущается. Впрочем, это только версия. Возможно, кто-то объяснит ситуацию иначе.

Comment: По мне, подставлять здесь пытаемся только мы с вами — читатель скорее вообще ничего не подставит :) И будет просто "поднять какую-то там зарплату".

Comment: Можно сказать, что притяжательное местоимение "его" чаще опускается и поэтому легко восстанавливается, в то время как пропущенное местоимение "ему"  не определяется столь же очевидно и предложение кажется незаконченным.